# Is there a way to download a project from github and place it in your project folder on maven build?

Tags: java, python, shell, maven, docker

I am working on an application where the project structure is as given below

Sample-Parent

```
    >Sample 

    >Sample packaging
```

Sample-Parent is the parent project which in turn is dependent on Sample and Sample Packaging modules.

Sample module contains the business code. 
Sample Packaging module contains the scripts to dockerize Sample Module.

All the applications in the project follows this standard.

We are planning to provide a seed project which provides a skeleton for this standard project structure so that any developer can start putting his business code and get his application up and running and need not worry about any configurations,which will be provided by seed project.

We are looking at developer not having to write any scripts to dockerize his project.

So the question is can we have a sample packaging project which has all the necessary scripts to dockerize any project, residing in github as a template project with the placeholders and if a new developer wants to dockerize his project say Sample-Dev1 , he does a maven build and it should perform the below steps
1.Download the sample-packaging project from the github .
2.Place it in the Sample-Dev1 project.
3.Replace all the place holders in sample-packaging project with sample-dev1 so that it dockerizes sample-dev1

This will be a great value add because the developer need not write any dockerizing script.

Which approach would be better? Any maven plugin that does this for me? or should I look at python scripts to do this? Or any better approach?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own maven nexus and import the jar file into it. Then add this lib as dependency into your project via maven (pom.xml)

[how to create maven nexus?](http://www.theserverside.com/news/1364121/Setting-Up-a-Maven-Repository)

[how to add jar into maven(local)?](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html)

[how to add jar into maven(remote)?](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-remote.html)

Answer (score 0):

Given these key requirements ...

> A Maven build (to) perform the below steps
>
> 1. Download the sample-packaging project
> 2. Place it in the Sample-Dev1 project
> 3. Replace all the place holders in sample-packaging project with sample-dev1

... a [Maven Archetype](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-archetypes.html) seems relevant.

An archetype is "an original pattern or model from which all other things of the same kind are made". Maven Archetypes allow you to define a parameterised version of your project. When someone uses your archetype they supply their own values for the parameters and Maven will generate a project with all of those parameters already substituted.

Creating a Maven Archetype is quite straightforward; here's a [guide](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-creating-archetypes.html) but in summary it involves creating your desired project structure (with parameter tokens in place for file names, values within files), then add an archetype descriptor and then bundle that as a Maven Archetype and install it in a repo for others to use.